# What is $(A\times B)^c$, given topological spaces $(X,T)$ and $(Y,T^*)$ and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$.?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,T)$ and $(Y,T^*)$ be two topological spaces and $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$. What is correct to use:

$1.(A\times B)^c=(A^c\times Y)\cup(X\times B^c)$, or
$2.(A\times B)^c=(A^c\times B)\cup(A\times B^c)\cup(A^c\times B^c)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)=\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780902/prove-that-a-times-b-setminusc-times-d-bigra-timesb-setminus-d-bigr-cu)

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct.

For $A\times B\subseteq X\times Y$ we have: $$(x,y)\in (A\times B)^{\complement}\iff x\notin A\text{ or } y\notin B\iff (x,y)\in A^{\complement}\times Y\text{ or }(x,y)\in X\times B^{\complement}$$

Comment: The second one is correct too, but we can simplify it to the first, noting that $A^\complement \times B \cup A^\complement \times B^\complement = A^\complement \times Y$ and similarly for the other term (we can use $ A^\complement \times B^\complement$ twice, to combine to form $X \times B^\complement$ too).